# Android: Alarm app best practices?

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms

I'm writing a simple alarm clock app to introduce myself further to android development.

I've looked at the android tutorials for alarms; for starting services and activities. In my case I want to set an alarm time, then start something that runs for say 1/2 hour after the alarm is fired.

During this 1/2 hour there will be background tasks happening but also on-screen information being displayed.

I am mostly curious as to what is best practice in this case. Should I run the background tasks as a service and the foreground as an activity? As the on screen activity is running at the same time as the background tasks would it be better just to run it all in an activity?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the best way is the way Google does it.
[Take a look.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/deskclock/AlarmClock.java#AlarmClock)